# How to redirect all requests except when there's an exact string match

Tags: nginx, rewrite, 301-redirect, ngx-http-rewrite-module

Requirement-
I want to redirect all requests that end with `/abcd` to `/products/abcd`

This should match all urls such as these-

- /collection/abcd
- /collections/all/abcd
- /hello/world/abcd

This is what i'm using-
`rewrite /abcd/?$ https://example.com/products/abcd permanent;`

The problem- if someone visits `/products/abcd`, this url also matches the rewrite rule, and goes into an infinite loop.

I also tried this regex, but that doesn't match any url (i.e. no redirects happen)- `rewrite /(^products/)abcd/?$ https://example.com/products/abcd permanent;`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, which uses nginx location blocks-

```
location /products {}
location / {
    rewrite /abcd/?$ https://example.com/products/abcd permanent;
}
```